# Getting return value problems with unittest patch() in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I am trying to use mock.patch to unittest my code, however I am getting a strange result. This is the important part of the code:

```
@mock.patch('benchmark.scenarios.networking.feature.ssh')
@mock.patch('benchmark.scenarios.networking.feature.subprocess.call')
def test_run_for_success(self, mock_subprocess, mock_ssh):
    mock_ssh.SSH().execute.return_value = (0, '100', '')
    mock_subprocess.call().return_value = 'mocked!'

    result = {}
    self.feature.run(result)
```

When I run ssh in my code, I get the returned value: `(0, '100', '')`, good! However, when I run `subprocess.call()` I get as returned value:

```
<MagicMock name='subprocess.call()' id='139806699670096'>
```

What am I doing wrong? I would like to get 'mocked!' as returned value.

Comment: Your mock is `benchmark.scenarios.networking.feature.subprocess.call`, then you're mocking the `call` method on that - you only need the `call` once, and the mock should match the `import`.

Answer (score 4):

You are using `mock.return_value` wrong, and on the wrong object; whenever you want to set the return value for `foo()`, use `foo.return_value`, not `foo().return_value`. Moreover, `mock_subprocess` points to `subprocess.call` *already*, don't look up the `call` attribute on that!

In other words, don't *call* the mock object when setting `return_value`, and use `mock_subprocess` *directly*:

```
mock_subprocess.return_value = 'mocked!'
```

You may want to rename `mock_subprocess` to `mock_subprocess_call` or similar to make that it obvious what you patched.

You were setting a return value for `subprocess.call.call()()`, not `subprocess.call()`.

Demo:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> from unittest.mock import patch
>>> with patch('subprocess.call') as mock_subprocess:
...     mock_subprocess.call().return_value = 'mocked!'
...     print(subprocess.call(), subprocess.call.call()())
...     mock_subprocess.return_value = 'mocked!'
...     print(subprocess.call())
...
<MagicMock name='call()' id='4557171960'> mocked!
mocked!
```